# How do I make the header and side-bar fixed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am following `MVC` approach where you can keep some contents `static` .i.e. header , footer , sidebar etc using `layout`.In my view, i want to make header and side-bar fixed while user `scroll-down` the page. Any help ?

Comment: I can't seem to relate MVC approach with layouts and any one part of your question.

Comment: I just want to make my header and side-bar static. now its clean !@Cthulhu

Answer (score 0):

Use `position : fixed` for your header div and sidebar div.

Answer (score 0):

You could definitely cleanup the sidebar and fixed positioning, but **[this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8yB9c/)** seems to work (quick mockup only). You'd need to add the CSS to your stylesheet, and then create partials for the header, sidebar and main content window.

In the CSS (below), you'd need to adjust some properties to make sure everything aligns properly as you're setting up your design.

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding:10px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.container { padding-top: 32px; } /* Adjust this value based on height of .header */

.main {
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: 30%;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 41px; /* Adjust this value based on height of .header and any additional padding */
    bottom: 0;
    width: 30%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```